# time expression + 置く

Tags: grammar, time

I've found this example sentence for 置く in my textbook:

> 三日置いて治った。(She recovered after three days).

I've looked this usage up but really couldn't find anything relevant. Could you clarify how and in what situations it's used? Many thanks.

Comment: Placed to heal for three days.

Comment: Placed or put for a period of time. https://jisho.org/search/置く%20

Comment: @JACK `Placed to heal for three days` <- 違います (> <)　この「置く」です→ https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41709/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11201/9831 The object of 置く is the period of time ("3日" "1日"), not the sick/injured person or injury/sickness. ◎「１日(を)おく」◎「3日(を)置いて(病気が)治った」 ✖「病気/病人を3日置く」

Comment: Jack: thanks but the link you provided only sends me to the general entry for 置く..

Chocolate: thanks, the similar questions you provided were helpful. I get it now.